# YUI compressor ignore errors

Tags: yui-compressor

I'm using YUI compressor in a bash script to minify .js files, but it throws errors and outputs a 0kb .min.js file if the original contains reserved keywords like `float` or `long`.

the bash script.sh example:

```
yui-compressor main.js > main.min.js
```

As the js compiles successfully in browser, is there a way using the above syntax to tell YUI compressor to ingnore any errors and compress the files anyway?

Comment: Your problems seems not related to `bash`, but rather seems `yui-compressor`-specific.

Comment: @KingThrushbeard, thanks, I've updated the tags